# can php "detect" redirects by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

(without PhantomJS)

I have a url that redirects by a js `location.replace` method.

Is there a way to get that final url in php?

Should I set headers/user agent or something like that?

Comment: If you want to be sure of the request's origin you can use CSRF protection.

Comment: Is not what I really want, but thanks for that, I didn`t know what CSFR is till now :)

Comment: Yes of course, you just parse the url out with regex.

Comment: @pguardiario what url are you talking about?

Comment: I'm saying the url will look like document.location='xxx' - that's something you can get with regex.

Comment: aaah, ok, I knew that :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put - No.

PHP runs on the server.
When all PHP scripts are complete, it returns HTML to the browser.

Javscript runs in the Browser.
When the HTML has loaded in the browser, JS does what it does.

At the point that your javascript is running, PHP has long finished and is sat patiently waiting for a new page load - and doesn't really care if the redirect was caused by JS or PHP.

Comment: But what if I read the source code and get the url within the `replace` method? Is this a good practice?

Comment: Not sure if its 'good practice', but presumably possible perhaps using DOM Document, or a regex match?

Comment: well, yeah, something like this...a regex will be more easy